# Logic of predicates over predicates?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, modal-logic

Is there logic, that allow to form predicates over predicates (or even formulas), I.e. derive is-interesting-statment(is(I, liar)). Of course, the model operators in the modal logic can take predicates and formulas as "arguments", but what about generalization of modal operators to the full expressiveness of arbitrary predicates? As I understand, then higher order logic is generalization about quantifiers and not the generalization that I am seeking. Generally, there is trend to express modalities using predicates, so, such generalization that I am seeking, should be possible, at least in the domain "modalities as predicates".

Comment: [Third-order logic and higher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_logic).

Comment: HOL is about putting the predicates under the scope of quantifiers. I cannot find HOL discourse which mentiond predicates over formulas.

Comment: For an example involving higher-order modal logic, see [Gödel's ontological proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del%27s_ontological_proof).

Comment: Quantification regards variables : individual (first-order), predicates (second-order), predicates of predicates (third-order), and so on. We don not quantifiy over formulas.